# How do you get entity's schema name using Code First (Entity Framework) and DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, schema, code-first, dbcontext

Our database was designed in such a way where there are various schemas for production and various equivalent schemas for test. For example, many tables rest in MyProduction schema while the same tables live in MyTest schema.

What I want to do is determine which schema a table is using so I know which one to change it to. So, by default, everything will be under the production schemas. In the OnModelCreating event of the DbContext, if I need to point to test (determined by some true/false configuration), I need to determine the production schema being used, then point it to it's test equivalent.

I'm already aware of how to set the schema but can't find how to get it. Any ideas how I can determine the schema that a table is using?

Thank You.

Comment: You don't need to get it - you are responsible for mapping so you define which schema and table the entity maps to.

Comment: I do need it. I have at least 6 separate schemas I have to use. Three schemas are for test and three for production. Each has 100s of tables in them. It will be much more efficient to write: if thisAnonymousTable is using this production schema then change it to MyTestSchema (if needed) rather than to manage three separate lists of 100s of tables each with their possible configurations. My classes and contexts are being generated from the EDM by the CodeFirstTemplate generator anyway so the schemas should be available to get. My question wasn't, do I need to do it, my question was how.ThankYou

Comment: Not that this matters but I could do this with NHibernate prior to switching to Entity Framework. I like Entity Framework much better but I still need to implement this functionality which is why I'm hoping to do it in the OnModelCreating event.

Comment: If you are using EDMX you cannot use OnModelCreating.

Comment: O.k. Let's say I get rid of EDMX so I can use OnModuleCreating and I take the time to place table annotations over my table classes and put a schema name in them : [Table("Authors",Schema="MyProdSchema")]. Is there a way to grab the annotation info from the entity within this event?

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code after modifying according to you local settings:**

```
var context = new YouDbContext("ConnectionName");
var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;
var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
EntitySetBase schema = null;
if (objectContext.MetadataWorkspace != null)
{
    schema = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
        .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace).First()
        .BaseEntitySets
        .First(meta => meta.ElementType.Name == "ClassNameUnderYourDbContext");
}
//See the properties of schema in debug mode to understand details
```

Comment: Remove .First(...) part from the query if you want to get all the schema.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587865/how-to-get-name-of-schema-from-entity-framework/18591456#18591456

Answer (score -1):

Entity Framework schemas are System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.TableAttribute objects. Here are some methods you can use to get an entitity's schema name and table name. Cheers!

```
    private string GetTableName(Type type)
    {
        var tableAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.TableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (tableAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableAttribute.Name))
        {
            return tableAttribute.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private string GetTableSchema(Type type)
    {
        var tableAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.TableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (tableAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableAttribute.Schema))
        {
            return tableAttribute.Schema;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute
```