# How to get name of schema from entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext, objectcontext

I have following code

```
using (WdmEntities context = new WdmEntities())
{
    //get object models from context
    ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var container = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
    List<string> schemas = new List<string>();
    foreach (var set in container.BaseEntitySets)
    {
        foreach (var metaproperty in set.MetadataProperties)
        {
            //here 
            if(metaproperty.Name == "Schema")
            {
                //but metaproperty.Value == NULL
                schemas.Add(metaproperty.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get null values  instead of schemas names. How i can get names of shemas from entity framework. (In my db i have two different shemas.) Maybe someone knows another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong approach. The code bellow shows how i was able to get the name of the schemes.

```
using (WdmEntities context = new WdmEntities())
{
    //get object models from context
    ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    //get all full names types from object model
    var fullNameTypes = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
    ///////////////////
    var conStr = objContext.Connection.ConnectionString;
    var connection = new EntityConnection(conStr);
    var workspace = connection.GetMetadataWorkspace();

    var entitySets = workspace.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace).First().BaseEntitySets;

    for (int i = 0; i < fullNameTypes.Count; i++)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(fullNameTypes[i].FullName);
        string schema = entitySets[type.Name].MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value.ToString();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this. It is well tested. Let me know if any doubt.**

```
using (var context = new WdmEntities())
                {
                    //get object models from context
                    var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
                    var items = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace);
                    var container = items != null ? items.First() : null;
                    var schemas = new List<string>();
                    if(container != null)
                        schemas = container.BaseEntitySets.Select(set => set.Name).ToList();
                }
```

Comment: Exception — The space 'SSpace' has no associated collection

Comment: @Mikhail, If you mean that 'SSpace' return no collection then I would it returns you a collection but always with a single item. That is why I am using First() method here. You can call it the CodeFirst approach implementation or by design.